# Informix Upper() not working with French characters

Tags: sql, ascii, informix, extended-ascii

It doesn't seem like the `upper()` function will capitalize French characters such as **ë**.

How can I add accent support on French characters when using upper?

```
-- Returns 0 rows
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE UPPER(NAME) = "NOËLLE";
```

We are using Informix 11.10 and the locale is set to `en_us.8859-1`.

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using?  Which code set (locale) is the database configured to use?  Which code set (locale) is your data entered in?  When I test with a database configured with `DB_LOCALE="en_us.utf8"` (and `CLIENT_LOCALE` set to the same too), the UPPER function works on UTF-8 data.   In another database with `DB_LOCALE=fr_fr.8859-15`, the UPPER function works correctly on 885015 characters, too. Copying the text from the question doesn't help; it's in UTF-8 — but that may or may not be the code set you're using.  The mapping worked with both an NVARCHAR and VARCHAR column.

Comment: JFTR: I tested on an antique Linux box (RedHat 5.3, I think) running Informix 12.10.FC9W1 (not antique, though not quite the most recent version).  I was driving it from a Unicode terminal on a Mac.  It was entertaining creating the 8859-15 accented data from UTF-8 data — sharp tools and a knowledge of `tr` got it done, though if I knew `iconv` well enough, it would probably have done the job more easily.

Comment: We're using Informix ver 11. The code set is en_us.8859-1 on all of our databases.

Comment: 11.10 or 11.50 or 11.70?   There’s quite a lot of time between the first and the last. I’ll poke at an `en_us.8859-1` database and see what I find.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the help. It's version 11.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with so much stuff, the problem is a compound of history and big customers.

Informix's default `en_us.8859-1` locale does not do case-mapping for accented characters, unlike almost any other locale.  There is an alternative that should be available to you — `en_us.8859-1@extn`.  You'd find it in `$INFORMIXDIR/gls/lc11/en_us` directory in the file `0333extn.lco` (there is a rationale behind the name; it is complex to explain).

Unfortunately, AFAICT, you'd have to rebuild the database with the alternative locale to get that to work — but when you do that, it does work.

Demonstration code is tricky — what you see in a browser is encoded in UTF-8 rather than 8859-1.  So, you have to know how to convert data from one code set to another — and the `iconv` command is probably your best friend here (it's a heap easier than using my ad hoc tooling).

I created the following file (UTF8) — `french-utf8.sql`:

```
begin;
create table french_test(name varchar(32) not null);
insert into french_test values("noëlle");
insert into french_test values("ç'est rien");
insert into french_test values("être");
insert into french_test values("à la mode");
insert into french_test values("café au lait");
select name, upper(name) from french_test;
```

There's a `BEGIN` but no `COMMIT` so that the changes to the database are not permanent (the transaction, including the CREATE TABLE statement, is rolled back).

That can be converted to 8859-1 using:

```
iconv -f utf8 -t iso-8859-1 french-utf8.sql > french-8859-1.sql
```

With accented characters mapped to `\xXY` hex escapes, the output becomes:

```
begin;
create table french_test(name varchar(32) not null);
insert into french_test values("no\xEBlle");
insert into french_test values("\xE7'est rien");
insert into french_test values("\xEAtre");
insert into french_test values("\xE0 la mode");
insert into french_test values("caf\xE9 au lait");
select name, upper(name) from french_test;
```

Run against a plain `en_us.8859-1` database, the output is:

```
no\xEBlle|NO\xEBLLE
\xE7'est rien|\xE7'EST RIEN
\xEAtre|\xEATRE
\xE0 la mode|\xE0 LA MODE
caf\xE9 au lait|CAF\xE9 AU LAIT
```

As you can see, the accented characters are not changed by `UPPER`, which is what you are/were observing as an issue.

Run against a database created with `en_us.8859-1@extn` (setting both `DB_LOCALE` and `CLIENT_LOCALE`), the output is:

```
no\xEBlle|NO\xCBLLE
\xE7'est rien|\xC7'EST RIEN
\xEAtre|\xCATRE
\xE0 la mode|\xC0 LA MODE
caf\xE9 au lait|CAF\xC9 AU LAIT
```

Here you can see that the output has mapped `\xE7` to `\xC7` and similarly for the other characters.

---

If you can't use the `en_us.8859-1@extn` locale, then you're probably reduced to the sequence of REPLACE operations shown by [The TTG Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1738572/the-ttg-guy) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48429054/15168).  Informix does not yet have a TRANSLATE function to map characters in bulk.

Comment: Wow, excellent answer and very informative. I understand this situation more clearly now and based on your suggestion switching to a different locale seems to be the best solution in order to keep the code clean. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested replace statements for each character you want to change. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(NAME),"ë","Ë"),"é","É")  = "NOËLLE";
```

Here is all of them:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 
UPPER(NAME),"à","À"),"â","Â"),"ä","Ä"),"æ","Æ"),"ç","Ç"),"é","É"),"è","È"),"ê","Ê"),"ë","Ë"),"î","Î"),"ï","Ï"),"ô","Ô"),"œ","Œ"),"ù","Ù"),"û","Û"),"ü","Ü")  = "NOËLLE";
```

Comment: True, however that's quite tedious